# How do I transform a python list to a dynamic frame that can be used to create a csv file in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I'm using aws glue with a custom pyspark script which loads data from an aurora instance and transforms it. Due to the nature of my data source (I need to recursively run sql commands on a list of ids) I ended up with a normal python list which contains lists of tuples. the list looks something like this:
`list = [[('id': 1), ('name1': value2),('name2': value2')], [('id': 2),...]`

I've tried to convert it into a normal data frame using spark's createDataFrameMethod:
`listDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(list)`

and converting that list to a dynamic Frame using the the fromDF method on the DynamicFrame class, ending up with something like this:
`listDynamicFrame = fromDF(dataframe = listDataFrame, glue_ctx = glueContext, name = listDynamicFrame)`

and then passing that to the from_options method:

```
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = 
 listDynamicFrame, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://glue.xxx.test"}, 
 format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
job.commit()
```

So yes, unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work: I'm getting the following error message:

```
1554379793700 final status: FAILED tracking URL: http://169.254.76.1:8088/cluster/app/application_1554379233180_0001 user: root
Exception in thread "main"
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1554379233180_0001 finished with failed status
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1122)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1168)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at  org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
19/04/04 12:10:00 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Comment: `this doesn't seem to work`
means you have what kind of error or result ?

Comment: hi Steve, ahh yes fair point, just updated the question with the error message

Comment: This error is generic one which almost always prints in logs when job is terminated due to failure. Are there any other errors in logs that are more specific?